# How to fix Bottom overflowed by 23 pixel

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hello, I'm new to flutter. I want to ask how to fix the Bottom overflowed by 23 pixels? I have added SingleChildScrollView but it still doesn't work even bottom overflowed by pixel still increases. It happened after I entered this code.

My code:

```
 new SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Container(
                              width: double.infinity,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                              //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                width: 1.0,
                              )),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 30,
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Employer',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
```

It happened after I added this code. I have used SingleChildScrollView but still no success. Please help.

Comment: Try removing Expanded above Column

Comment: Still the same. The error still cannot be fixed.

Comment: wrap the parent widget of your container with SingleChildScrollView. Because the container alone seems to work fine, so I think the problem is with the parent widget

Comment: I'm done to wrap with SingleChildScrollView but still the same. Error still can't fix.

Comment: can you provide us with the full code of the page posted in the question?

Comment: I'm done editing my code. Please see. This error still can't fix.

Comment: I mean all the code that contains text fields in the image posted in your question

Comment: This doesn't look like the full widget that is in the image. Can you add the rest?

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring because whatever the SingleChildScrollView is inside of is not scrollable.

Comment: Not enough space. Can give me the solution for posting all code for this page?

Comment: just try to wrap the container, text fields and all other contents in this page with SingleChildScrollView. you made it the parent only for the container, go up until you reach the last parent and wrap it with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: Post your entire code here : https://codeshare.io/yoEmvq

Comment: Sure, wait. I post the code at your link given to me.

Comment: Please see my code. https://codeshare.io/yoEmvq

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Container` with `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

```
return SingleChildSCrollView(
 child: Container(
 // your code here
  ), //Container
); //SingleChildScrollView
```

Comment: Still the same. The error still cannot be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

in your Scaffold widget set the attribute resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false,

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      ....
      ....
);
```

Comment: Still can't fix this problem.